# Ansible json_query'd json to yaml inventory with variables

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory, jmespath

I have an ansible json_query'd result that I'm trying to use as the inventory for another playbook and my noob skills at manipulating data are lacking.

The json_query is:

```
community.general.json_query('device_info.value[].{ hostname: DeviceName, serial: DeviceServiceTag, model: Model, connected: ConnectionState, networkaddress: DeviceManagement[0].NetworkAddress }')
```

With the results being something like this (100+ hosts in real world):

```
[
  {
    "hostname": "thingy1.company.org",
    "serial": "serial1",
    "model": "modelA",
    "connected": true,
    "networkaddress": "1.2.3.4"
  },
  {
    "hostname": "thingy2.company.org",
    "serial": "serial2",
    "model": "modelB",
    "connected": true,
    "networkaddress": "1.2.3.5"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to convert this result into a usable yaml inventory file. Here is what I'm trying to get to.

```
groupname:
  hosts:
    thingy1.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelA
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
      serial: serial1
    thingy2.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelB
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
      serial: serial2
```

Any tips to help a noob out?

Answer (score 1):

Given the list

```yaml
  result_list:
    - connected: true
      hostname: thingy1.company.org
      model: modelA
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
      serial: serial1
    - connected: true
      hostname: thingy2.company.org
      model: modelB
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
      serial: serial2
```

Declare the dictionary

```yaml
  result_dict: "{{ dict(result_list|map(attribute='hostname')|
                        zip(result_list)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result_dict:
    thingy1.company.org:
      connected: true
      hostname: thingy1.company.org
      model: modelA
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
      serial: serial1
    thingy2.company.org:
      connected: true
      hostname: thingy2.company.org
      model: modelB
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
      serial: serial2
```

---

You can remove the attribute *hostname*

```yaml
  result_dict: "{{ dict(result_list|map(attribute='hostname')|
                        zip(result_list|
                            ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['hostname']))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result_dict:
    thingy1.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelA
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
      serial: serial1
    thingy2.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelB
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
      serial: serial2
```

---

Write the dictionary to the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/my_hosts.yaml
        content: |
          groupname:
            hosts:
          {{ result_dict|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(4, first=true) }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/my_hosts.yaml
groupname:
  hosts:
    thingy1.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelA
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
      serial: serial1
    thingy2.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelB
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
      serial: serial2
```

---

You can change the query

```yaml
  result_list: "{{ device_info.value|community.general.json_query(my_query) }}"
  my_query: '[].{key: DeviceName, value: {serial: DeviceServiceTag, model: Model, connected: ConnectionState, networkaddress: DeviceManagement[0].NetworkAddress}}'
```

and get the list

```yaml
  result_list:
    - key: thingy1.company.org
      value:
        connected: true
        model: modelA
        networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
        serial: serial1
    - key: thingy2.company.org
      value:
        connected: true
        model: modelB
        networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
        serial: serial2
```

It's trivial to change this list to the dictionary

```yaml
  result_dict: "{{ result_list|items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result_dict:
    thingy1.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelA
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.4
      serial: serial1
    thingy2.company.org:
      connected: true
      model: modelB
      networkaddress: 1.2.3.5
      serial: serial2
```